# unable to find model class in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am using yii2 advance project

> namespace frontend\models;
>
> use Yii;
>
> use frontend\models\Emailtemplate;

and then below in class i am using

> Emailtemplate::find()->where(['email_code'=>Yii::$app->params['FORGOTPASSWORD'],'is_active'=>Yii::$app->params['is_active_yes']])->one();

but it showing me an error message

```
name: "PHP Fatal Error",
message: "Class 'frontend\models\Emailtemplate' not found",
```

Please help me to solve the issue

Comment: Have you double checked the "Emailtemplate" name? its case sensitive

Comment: @saquib thank you for your replay. it is "EmailTemplate".I made a  silly mistake

Comment: No problem. It happens with all of us. Happy Coding :)

Comment: happy coding :)